# Not able to load Bitmap from resource

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I'm having trouble to load a bitmap from resource. I have a project that I want to maintain.
The images are being loaded from files, but I want to load them from resource.

So, the code below is working:

```
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("C:\\nananana...");
pBitmapClose = Bitmap::FromFile(path);
```

But, when I try to use from resource, it is not working. I have tried several parameters as bellow:

```
pBitmapClose = Bitmap::FromResource(g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BTN_CLOSE));
```

or

```
pBitmapClose = Bitmap::FromResource((HINSTANCE) GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BTN_CLOSE));
```

Can anyone PLEASE help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Are you getting an error? Or is the bitmap just not showing up?

Comment: Have you considered using the `CBitmap` class?

Comment: Did you verify that the bitmap is actually in the app's resources, and using the actual ID number that you are expecting?

Comment: Get the error code and check it after failed Bitmap load. That'll give you clue of what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What format are your resources in?

GDI+ can only load bitmap (.BMP) images from resources. If you want to load PNG or JPG images from a resource you need to kludge it using a stream. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3537/Loading-JPG-PNG-resources-using-GDI for a handy class that can do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
BOOL  CreateBitmap(LPCTSTR szFileName)
{
    if(::PathFileExists(szFileName))
        m_pBitmap = Bitmap::FromFile(T2CW(szFileName));
    else
    {
        m_pBitmap = Bitmap::FromResource( ModuleHelper::GetResourceInstance(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_NOFIND));
    }
    return !IsNull();
}
```

// the code will work